# Access user before controllers load in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

## Question:

How do I load the logged in user "before" controllers are initiated, or at least within the constructor.

### System:

- Laravel 10

### Detail

I'm attempting to save a *lot* of repeated code by loading a few logged in user items at, or before the controller level. Ideally, this should be done in the base `Controller`. This will save possibly hundreds of lines of duplicated code.

If I use auth()->user() in the controller methods, this all works as expected.

The middleware for auth is not loaded when the constructor of either the `Controller` or an extended controller, eg: `UserController`. I have also tried this in the `AppServiceProvider` and this is still true.

I am aware that this is the case... so how do I change the system to authenticate earlier, or manually call the load of the authenticated user?

I simply need to load the user from somewhere. Thus - is there a cookie or session I can directly load this from?

(Note, these are NOT security issues.. the auth middleware is locking this down reliably - I am using the logged in user to change non-security layout options and non-sensitive data loaded)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow the instructions for Laravel 5.7 in the duplicate, it works in Laravel 10. Basically you need to call the middleware in the constructor and you'll be able to use `auth()` functions in the callback.